# Is there a word for someone who completely agrees with a political party's platform?

Tags: word-choice

> Joe, a <this word> Republican, believes that high taxes and strict business regulations hurt the economy, supports gun rights, and believes abortion should be illegal.

> John, a <this word> Democrat, supports abortion rights and climate action, opposes tax cuts that benefit billionaires at the expense of the average American, and believes guns should be banned or at least strictly regulated.

What could I use for <this word>? The goal is to show that they entirely agree with the respective party's platform and do not object to any part.

(Obviously, these examples don't cover the entire platforms of the Republican and Democratic parties, but I think they're sufficient to show what I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 2):

[Devoted](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/devoted) or similar words might fit  (ardent, staunch, true, zealous, [hard-line](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/hard-line), uncompromising).

You could also go with something like "[Kool-Aid drinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_the_Kool-Aid)", though that has negative connotations.

Answer (score 2):

Staunch.

> Joe, a staunch Republican, believes that high taxes and strict business regulations hurt the economy, supports gun rights, and believes abortion should be illegal.

> John, a staunch Democrat, supports abortion rights and climate action, opposes tax cuts that benefit billionaires at the expense of the average American, and believes guns should be banned or at least strictly regulated.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! It's probably a good idea to use the preview function, to make sure that your markdown is doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

## A few thoughts:

I can think of a few words that work, depending on the emotional impact desired.

- Die-hard
- Loyalist (or party loyalist if only for politics)
- Fanatical
- Extremist
- Faithful
- Reflexive
- card-carrying
- Uncompromising

Comment: The context is giving instructions for someone to write a short essay on their political beliefs. "A [this] Republican may write..., while a [this] Democrat might write..."

Comment: @Someone Ah, so only positive descriptors. I've rarely heard a die-hard political person denigrate their loyalty.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *unthinking*.

Anyone who agrees with the entirety of a political party's platform hasn't understood it all or thought about it.

But I bet that isn't the word you want!